# in istio, how a virtualservice defined in a namespace can use a gateway defined in another namespace

Tags: kubernetes, istio, gateway, service-virtualization

If a `virtualservice` `A` is defined in `namespace` `A` using `networking.istio.io`, how can it use a `gateway` `B` defined in another namespace, `namespace` `B`?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it´s not in the same namespace as virtual service, you have to specify that in virtual service

Check the `spec.gateways` section

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-Mongo
  namespace: bookinfo-namespace
spec:
  gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/my-gateway # can omit the namespace if gateway is in same
                                       namespace as virtual service.
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: some-config-namespace
```

There is related  [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) about that.

Comment: Thanks. Would the dot notion work too? like: `gateways: my-gateway.some-config-namespace`

Comment: @imriss In the documentation there is only the option with my-gateway/some-config-namepsace, so I would say it won´t work with dot.

Comment: it doesn't work with dot, it only works with slash, I just had this issue and using slash solved the problem

Comment: FYI, if you are communicating from namespace to namespace, the namespace you communicate to has a subdomain in the url: http://(service-name).(namespace):(port)